# Show loading gif image until success of function

Tags: javascript

I want to show a loading gif image on call of function and want to display it until the end till success.

I want to show the image on following button click:

```js
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="margin-left: 7%; width: 50%;"
        id="Submit" name="Submit" onclick="prepareDataValueSet()">
  SYNC
</button>
```

Now on start of `prepareDataValueSet()` I want to show a gif image and want to hide it at the end.

```
$('#loading').show(); // I am using this to show image
$('#loading').hide(); // and this for hiding it
```

Can anybody help me in this case or supply a link to any tutorial for how to insert a loading image or progress bar for specific time?

Following is my complete function : I want to show image at start of function and want to hide it at the success:

```js
 function prepareDataValueSet() {


            $('#loading').show();
         
            deMapping = {

                RBSK: {
                    'dsUID': 'tdTwLUxcQ8R', rootNodeName: 'RBSK_GIS_Indicator', url: baseURL+"/documents/NnxD6b7jqUr/data",orgUnitTagName: 'MCTSCode', des: [
                        {
                            xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Female",
                            dataElement: "123",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ",
                            value:"0"

                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Male",
                            dataElement: "123",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_7_18_Female",
                            dataElement: "cEPledgs7rd",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_7_18_Male",
                            dataElement: "cEPledgs7rd",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "Deficiencies_0_6_Female",
                            dataElement: "gKupqkIhW4n",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "Deficiencies_0_6_Male",
                            dataElement: "gKupqkIhW4n",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "Deficiencies_7_18_Female",
                            dataElement: "FuEnn0bLuoT",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "Deficiencies_7_18_Male",
                            dataElement: "FuEnn0bLuoT",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_0_6_Female",
                            dataElement: "v37HBq7C72j",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_0_6_Male",
                            dataElement: "v37HBq7C72j",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_7_18_Female",
                            dataElement: "S1WMlAKnF8Z",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_7_18_Male",
                            dataElement: "S1WMlAKnF8Z",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb",
                            value:""
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "defect_at_birth_0_6_Female",
                            dataElement: "JJO3utHjb3l",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "defect_at_birth_0_6_Male",
                            dataElement: "JJO3utHjb3l",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "defect_at_birth_7_18_Female",
                            dataElement: "qoVmtykHboz",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ",
                            value:"0"
                        },
                        {
                            xmlid: "defect_at_birth_7_18_Male",
                            dataElement: "qoVmtykHboz",
                            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb",
                            value:"0"
                        }
                    ]
                }

            };
            console.log("Url "+ deMapping[selectedText].url);
            for (var k = 0; k < deMapping[selectedText].des.length;k++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < dataelements.length; j++) {

                    if (deMapping[selectedText].des[k].dataElement == dataelements[j]) {

                        deMapping[selectedText].des[k].value =1;
                        var vf=  deMapping[selectedText].des[k].value;

                        msg1 += deMapping[selectedText].des[k].dataElement + ',';



                    }

                }
                if(deMapping[selectedText].des[k].value=="1")
                {
console.log("Mapped Data Elements: "+deMapping[selectedText].des[k].xmlid)


                }
else if(deMapping[selectedText].des[k].value=="0")
                {
//                    console.log("UnMapped Data Elements: "+deMapping[selectedText].des[k].xmlid)

                    ade +=deMapping[selectedText].des[k].xmlid + "<br>";
                    document.getElementById("qwe4").innerHTML = "<b>"+"Data Elements for following tags not Found in DHIS2"+"</b>" + "<br>" + ade +"<br>";
                }

            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: deMapping[selectedText].url,
                dataType: "xml",
                async: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                headers: {},
                success: function (xml) {

                    $(xml).find(deMapping[selectedText].rootNodeName).each(function () {
                        var m0 = $(this).find(deMapping[selectedText].orgUnitTagName).text();
                        mstc.push(m0);
                        for (var k = 0; k < deMapping[selectedText].des.length; k++) {

                            mapDataValue[m0 + ":" + deMapping[selectedText].des[k].xmlid] = $(this).find(deMapping[selectedText].des[k].xmlid).text();
                        }
                    });


                }


            });


            var dataValueSet = {};
            var dataValues = [];


            for (var i = 0; i < mstc.length; i++) {

                if (dmap[map[mstc[i]]] == undefined) {
                    msg += mstc[i] + ',';
                }

                else if (dmap[map[mstc[i]]] != undefined) {


                    var org = map[mstc[i]];
                    for (var k = 0; k < deMapping[selectedText].des.length; k++) {

                        if (deMapping[selectedText].des[k].value == "1") {
                            dataValue = {};
                            dataValue["orgUnit"] = org;
                            dataValue["period"] = selectedText_year + selectedText_month;
                            dataValue["dataElement"] = deMapping[selectedText].des[k].dataElement;
                            dataValue["categoryOptionCombo"] = deMapping[selectedText].des[k].categoryOptionCombo;
                            dataValue["value"] = mapDataValue[mstc[i] + ":" + deMapping[selectedText].des[k].xmlid];
                            dataValues.push(dataValue);


                            dataValueSet.dataValues = dataValues;

                        }
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        url: baseURL + '/dataValueSets',
                        data: JSON.stringify(dataValueSet),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'post',
                        async: false,
                        success: returnSuccess,
                        error: returnError

                    });

                    function returnSuccess(response) {

                        $('#loading').hide();


                    }

                    function returnError(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#loading').hide();
                        alert("inside error");
                  

                    }



                }
             

            }



           

        }
```

Comment: What do you want? You already know what how you need to do it.

Comment: can you share your  `prepareDataValueSet()` function?

Comment: Is there any AJAX call inside `prepareDataValueSet()`?

Comment: please share your javascript code. you can also use plugins to display progressbar or loading image

Comment: You are going good. What is no working ? `show()` the loader before ajax call and `hide` it after `success` or `error` *callback*

Comment: Image is showing properly but I need to run it for specific time only like when I click on button image comes up but i need to hide it at the end of processing here in success function i want to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the provided code, the part you're missing is not in the JS, but actually in the HTML: the `img` tag is missing.

```js
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="margin-left: 7%; width: 50%;"
        id="Submit" name="Submit" onclick="prepareDataValueSet()">
  SYNC
</button>
<img src="../path/to/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." id="loading" style="display:none" />
```

Of course you will need to position the `img` tag properly with some CSS to have it on the button.

Another solution would have been to use CSS class to add/remove the gif as a `background-image` on the button directly. Much easier to handle.

Comment: Image is showing properly but I need to run it for specific time only like when I click on button image comes up but i need to hide it at the end of processing here in success function i want to hide it.

Comment: Can you add a break point in your success callback and check that `$('#loading').hide();` is called? Because from your code, everything seems correct.